# Terraform / AWS stuck in "still destroying..." subnet and security group steps when applying

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, amazon-vpc

I am creating a scraped data cleaning pipeline in aws using terraform so I can reuse the configuration later too for other use-cases.
Infra steps:

- Upload csv to an S3 bucket
- Trigger Lambda function to

  - Clean the data
  - Upload to a different S3 bucket
  - Insert into RDS instance with Postgres engine

I have successfully set it up all to provision all the resources except for the RDS DB. The problem is my lack of experience with AWS VPC configurations. In that I tried setting things up in the following way:

```
provider "aws" {
    region     = var.aws_region
    access_key = var.aws_access_key
    secret_key = var.aws_secret_key
}
    
data "aws_vpc" "default" {
    default = true
}

resource "aws_db_subnet_group" "rds_subnet_group" {
    name       = "scrapr-rds-subnet-group"
    subnet_ids = [aws_subnet.main.id, aws_subnet.secondary.id]
}

resource "aws_subnet" "main" {
    vpc_id            = data.aws_vpc.default.id
    cidr_block        = "10.0.1.0/24"
    availability_zone = "eu-central-1a"
}

resource "aws_subnet" "secondary" {
    vpc_id            = data.aws_vpc.default.id
    cidr_block        = "10.0.2.0/24"
    availability_zone = "eu-central-1b"
}
```

I tried using a custom VPC before with CIDR block of `10.0.0.0/16`. I suspect something may have messed up when I switched VPC configs from custom to default, but again... lack of experience in this.

I want to be able to be able to read/write using the lambda and from a local connection using for example pgAdmin. The `rds_security_group` is set up as follows but may not be the correct way to achieve it so some support on it would be well appreciated too.

```
resource "aws_security_group" "rds_security_group" {
    name        = "scrapr_rds_security_group"
    description = "Security group for Scrapr RDS instance"
    vpc_id      = data.aws_vpc.default.id

    ingress {
        from_port   = 5432
        to_port     = 5432
        protocol    = "tcp"
        cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    }
    ingress {
        from_port = 5432
        to_port   = 5432
        protocol  = "tcp"
    }

    egress {
        from_port   = 0
        to_port     = 0
        protocol    = "-1"
        cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    }
}

resource "aws_security_group" "lambda_security_group" {
    name        = "scrapr_lambda_security_group"
    description = "Security group for Scrapr Lambda function"
    vpc_id      = data.aws_vpc.default.id

    # Allow outbound connections to the RDS instance
    egress {
        from_port = 0
        to_port   = 0
        protocol  = "-1"
    }
}
```

The db and lambda configs:

```
resource "aws_db_instance" "scrapr_rds_instance" {
    identifier             = "scrapr-rds-instance"
    engine                 = "postgres"
    engine_version         = "14.7"
    instance_class         = "db.t3.micro"
    allocated_storage      = 20
    storage_type           = "gp2"
    username               = var.db_username
    password               = var.db_password
    db_subnet_group_name   = aws_db_subnet_group.rds_subnet_group.name
    vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.rds_security_group.id]
    publicly_accessible    = false
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "processing_lambda" {
    function_name = "processing_lambda"
    ...
    vpc_config {
        subnet_ids         = [aws_subnet.main.id]
        security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.lambda_security_group.id]
    }
}
```

The problem is that in the `terraform apply` the subnet and security_group are stuck in this loop:

```
>aws_security_group.lambda_security_group: Still destroying... [4m0s elapsed]
>aws_security_group.lambda_security_group: Still destroying... [4m10s elapsed]
>aws_subnet.main: Still destroying... [4m10s elapsed]
>aws_subnet.main: Still destroying... [4m20s elapsed]
>aws_security_group.lambda_security_group: Still destroying... [4m20s elapsed]
>aws_security_group.lambda_security_group: Still destroying... [4m30s elapsed]
>aws_subnet.main: Still destroying... [4m30s elapsed]
>aws_security_group.lambda_security_group: Still destroying... [4m40s elapsed]
>aws_subnet.main: Still destroying... [4m40s elapsed]
>aws_security_group.lambda_security_group: Still destroying... [4m50s elapsed]
>aws_subnet.main: Still destroying... [4m50s elapsed]
```

I am getting desperate so any help would be very much appreciated <3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lot of info in your question, and a lot of side questions about how to properly configure a VPC, which should really be posted here as a separate question. It looks like you have made some sort of change to your Terraform code that is requiring it to delete the existing Lambda security group, and also an existing VPC subnet, but that delete process is taking forever. I'm going to focus on that specific part of the question since that is also the problem you reference in the question title.

**Dealing with your specific resource deletion issue:**

When you deploy a Lambda function to a VPC, AWS will automatically create an [Elastic Network Interface](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-eni.html) (ENI) inside your VPC for the Lambda function to use. Since that ENI isn't managed by Terraform directly, Terraform isn't going to know that it needs to delete it before it can delete the security group that ENI is using, or the subnet that ENI is in. You will have to go find that ENI in the AWS web console and delete it manually. Or if you delete the Lambda function completely the ENI should also be deleted (although that can take some time).

---

**Dealing with Terraform AWS resource deletion issues in general:**

Terraform is great at creating resources, but not the best at deleting/cleaning-up those resources. Sometimes other dependent resources get created outside Terraform, either manually or automatically, so Terraform doesn't know to delete those. Other times the order that resources need to be deleted is just not easy for Terraform to discover.

If you use Terraform often enough you will undoubtedly run into this issue where it can't delete something. The best fix is generally to go into the AWS console and just try to delete the same resource yourself, and see what error Amazon gives you about a dependent resource that needs to be deleted first. Once you have cleaned up those things manually, run Terraform again and it will see that the resources have already been deleted and be able to continue with the resource provisioning.

---

**Regarding your issues setting up a VPC via Terraform:**

If you aren't sure how to setup a VPC from scratch, I highly recommend using [this Terraform module](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws/latest) to handle that for you, or at least looking at the source code for that module to see how it should be done.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer! Deleting the Lambda function worked but indeed I will be using that module from now on! I was cautious of manually deleting the resources on the console because I read something about the state file getting out of sync and I didn't want to open that can of worms. Again I appreciate the help!